# XAML ListBox Binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, listbox

I'm working on a GIS website in C# and Silverlight, and I'm trying to populate a ListBox based on map layers.  The code works if I lump everything together in a single XAML file (where the Map is defined in the same file), but I am trying to separate things into separate classes, and the ListBox will not populate in the other class.

XAML Code..

```
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Visible, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <Slider Margin="-5,0,0,0" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Width="30" 
                Value="{Binding Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="18" />-->

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="5,0,0,0" > 

            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <StackPanel MaxWidth="400">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding CopyrightText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
            </TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
```

myMap is being set when the class is called by this C# code...

public partial class TableOfContents : UserControl
{
    Map myMap;

```
public TableOfContents(ref Map map)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myMap = map;

    foreach (Layer thisLayer in myMap.Layers)
    {
        layerList.Items.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = thisLayer.ID });
    }
}
```

}

The foreach statement adds TextBlocks for all of the map layers (this is just test code), so I know the information is being passed correctly, but the data binding defined in XAML doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
The XAML Code seems to be clipped in the post (although it's visible when I edit it).  The data binding is defined by:
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Layers, ElementName=myMap}

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot - ItemsSource="{Binding myMap.Layers}".

Maybe a simpler option would be setting "this.DataContext = map" in the constructor. Binding would then look like: ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}". You could remove myMap completely.